# Batch download file from internet?

Tags: downloads

Say I want to download lot of image files from example.com/image001.jpg to example.com/image150.jpg. The example.com site have a lot of images from image000.jpg to image999.jpg, the images i want just from image001.jpg to image150.jpg (150 files).

Is there any command line or GUI tool to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a GUI to do such a task, the Firefox extension Down Them All allows you to set ranges like you specify in your questions.  Click the plus sign in the Down Them All manager and add your range like image[000-150].jpg.

Comment: Is there any Chrome/Chromium equivalent? I wont use Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that comes close to Down Them All.  It's too bad you won't use Firefox--I sometimes start up Firefox just so I can use Down Them All and, to a lesser extent, VideoDownload Helper.

Comment: Well I guess I don't have a choice right now, your solution is work anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a little shell script:

```
for i in `seq -w 150`
do 
  wget -c http://example.com/image$i.jpg
done
```

There are also guis like gwget that can do this.

Comment: I can't get these command to work it give me HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2013-06-18 08:53:56 ERROR 403: Forbidden. I can directly access the file using browser

Comment: How do I install gwget? Maybe it can work.. It's not in 13.04 repository.

Comment: That's probably because the website is trying to block batch downloads.  Try with a browser-integrated tool like [Flashget](http://www.flashget.com/en/download.htm).

Comment: It's not, I can do batch download using IDM under windows, I just need to know how do I do it in Ubuntu. This is the URL http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/583/01-001.0/compressed/jigoku_sensei_nube01_c01p0$$.jpg, $$ is from 01 to 50

Comment: That works for me.  Make sure you're generating the right number of digits: `seq -w` will make them all equal in width to the highest number, which for this example will be 001..150.  Try changing `wget -c` to `echo` to make sure it's generating the right URLs.

Comment: I've tried changing wget to echo and it give the right URLs. this is my script is this right? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75813759/new

Comment: The script is right but the server seems to have some kind of bulk-download prevention heuristic. Bypassing that is probably not on topic for askubuntu.

Comment: I see, well I just need to use firefox extension to do that, although I want a script or CLI way, but thats fine, thanks for your help.